# How to add ssmtp into initramfs?

Tags: dynamic-linking, initrd, ssmtp

I'm trying to add ssmtp into initramfs. However, I can not find (or compile at the moment) the statically linked version. I guess my only option is adding the current, dynamically linked version.

I'm trying to add the binary (`which ssmtp`) and its dependencies (`ldd $(which ssmtp)`) to the initramfs. Although `ssmtp` works fine in my system, I can not find one of the `ldd /usr/sbin/ssmtp` output in anywhere:

```
$ ldd /usr/sbin/ssmtp
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc661ca000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fd8ffc7e000)
    libgnutls-openssl.so.27 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls-openssl.so.27 (0x00007fd8ffa75000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd8ff8b8000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007fd8ff54d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd8ffefa000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd8ff32f000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fd8ff002000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fd8fede3000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fd8fec5f000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007fd8fea4c000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007fd8fe815000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007fd8fe5df000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007fd8fe35b000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fd8fe150000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd8fe14b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd8fe12a000)


$ find / -name linux-vdso.so.1 2> /dev/null
# finds nothing
```

So, how can I install ssmtp into initramfs (or more generally, I can I install a dynamically linked binary into the initramfs)?

Comment: You can add libc to initramfs, but it is better if you recompile it with klibc. All the initramfs-based debian binaries have a micro klibc version and this is going into initramfs.

Comment: why are you adding ssmtp to initramfs?

Comment: @peterh I may try again to compile and link it statically. Thanks.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have a setup where the IP address is changed in random cases. If machine reboots, I need to know the IP address to connect and open the encrypted partition so the boot process can continue.

Comment: You want to send mails from the initramfs? It could work, but then you have to also set up networking already in the initramfs. If your goal is simply to get a mail on any reboot, then cron is your best option. (Cron can have things which will happen on boot and not on any time)

Comment: Btw, probably you can't recompile ssmtp with klibc, it uses a lot of other libs and you should port to klibc also them.

Comment: Yes, I want to send mails from the initramfs. The boot process can not continue unless the LUKS password has been entered, so my only option is performing this task at the initramfs stage. I've already set up the networking stuff, I've an ssh server listening. The only thing I need to do is to get the external IP address of the server, and this has to be done before OS is actually booted up. There might be simpler options though, like simply making a connection to a known server. I'm also evaluating msmtp at the moment. Last resort for the mail task might be using Slitaz instead of initramfs.